# Why alarms does not raise on time?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications, alarm, raise

I am setting an alarm in my app. I have used alarm manager and broadcast receiver for this. The problem is alarm does not raise on time.

Sometimes it does raise on time and sometimes does not. If multiple alarms has been set, all alarms raises at same time.

I tried using setInexactRepeating, setRepeating, for both the cases its happening like this. I want the alarm to repeat weekly.

Please help don't know what's wrong.

Notification function

```
public void setNotificationTime(Calendar c)
{

    Date dateFrom = new Date();
    df = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
    try {
        dateFrom = df.parse(startTime);
    }
    catch (ParseException ex) {

    }

    dateFrom.getTime();
    c.setTime(dateFrom);

    hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);


    if(notificationTime.equals("10 Minutes Before"))
    {


        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute - 10);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.DATE, day);
        // c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,);

        SetDay(c);

        notification = c.getTime();
        notificationTime = df.format(notification);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),notificationTime,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),NotificationReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),RQS_1, intent, 0);
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pendingIntent);

    }



    else if(notificationTime.equals("30 Minutes Before"))
    {

        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute - 30);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.DATE, day);
        // c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,);

        SetDay(c);

        notification = c.getTime();
        notificationTime = df.format(notification);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),notificationTime,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),NotificationReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),RQS_1, intent, 0);
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pendingIntent);

    }



    else if(notificationTime.equals("1 Hour Before"))
    {

        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour - 1);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.DATE, day);
        // c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,);

        SetDay(c);

        notification = c.getTime();
        notificationTime = df.format(notification);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),notificationTime,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),NotificationReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),RQS_1, intent, 0);
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pendingIntent);

    }



    else if(notificationTime.equals("2 Hours Before"))
    {

        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour - 2);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.DATE, day);
        // c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,);

        SetDay(c);

        notification = c.getTime();
        notificationTime = df.format(notification);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),notificationTime,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),NotificationReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),RQS_1, intent, 0);
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pendingIntent);

    }
}
```

NotificationReceiver

```
 public class NotificationReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver {


    public static int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;
    NotificationManager notificationManager;
    Notification myNotification;

    EventTableHelper db;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        Toast.makeText(context, "Time is set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        db = new EventTableHelper(context);

        List<EventData> testSavings = db.getAllEvents();

        for (EventData ts : testSavings) {
            String log = "from date:" + ts.getFromDate()
                    + " ,to date: " + ts.getToDate()
                    + " ,location: " + ts.getLocation()
                    + " ,title " + ts.getTitle();

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date date = new Date();
            Date date1 = new Date();
            Log.d("Result: ", log);

            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
            SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");

            try {
                date = df.parse(ts.getFromDate());
                date1 = df.parse(ts.getToDate());
            } catch (ParseException ex) {

            }
            String timeFrom = df2.format(date);
         //   String startTime = String.valueOf(timeFrom);

            String timeTo = df2.format(date1);
           // String endTime = String.valueOf(timeTo);


            String location = ts.getLocation();
            String title = ts.getTitle();


            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    context,
                    0,
                    myIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            if(location.equals(""))
            {
                String msg = "From : " + timeFrom + "\nTo : " + timeTo;

                myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setContentTitle("Event : " + title)
                        .setContentText(msg)
                        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.eventicon)
                        .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                        .build();

            }

            else
            {
                String msg = "From : " + timeFrom + "\nTo : " + timeTo + "\nAt : " + location;
                myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setContentTitle("Event : " + title)
                        .setContentText(msg)
                        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.eventicon)
                        .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                        .build();

            }

            Log.i("Notify", "Notification");
            notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, myNotification);

            myNotification.flags=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.putExtra("notificationId",MY_NOTIFICATION_ID);

            MY_NOTIFICATION_ID ++;

        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you target API level 19+ on a 4.4+ device ? If so there is no method to schedule an exact repeating event. See [AlarmManager.setRepeating()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) :

> Note: as of API 19, **all repeating alarms are inexact**. If your
>   application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time
>   exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above. Legacy
>   applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will
>   continue to have all of their alarms, including repeating alarms,
>   treated as exact.

I think this is by design, to dissuade developpers :waking up the device drains the battery quicker.

Comment: Yes I have read this. But why all alarms raises at same time sometimes? Is it the same reason for that or if am i mistaking something in my code?

Comment: What can I do to avoid this inexact time? @bwt

Comment: Inexact alarms allow the devices to wake up once and process multiples alarms. On 19+ you can use `setExact()` and handle the repeat yourself, i.e. schedule each time the next week.